# Auxiliary to be with first person singular

Tags: sentence-meaning, grammaticality

A. If I was you, I would help the poor
B. If I were you, I would help the poor

Which of the sentences is correct, A, B or both

Comment: Both are perfectly acceptable. This "were" is called 'irrealis mood', an untidy relic of an earlier system. Some speakers usually, if not always, use preterite "was" as in your first example.

Comment: The more usual term is "subjunctive mood" or more specifically "past subjunctive"

Comment: It's not the subjunctive mood. A subjunctive clause is headed by a plain form verb, as in "It is vital that I **be** kept informed" / "He insisted that I **meet** her". It's a nonsense that "were" is a past subjunctive form since it has nothing whatsoever to do with past time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B is correct, because this isn't just a regular past tense sentence, it's in subjunctive mood, which is used for hypothetical situations, which is what this one is.

http://www.grammar.cl/english/if-i-were-you.htm

Comment: While the answer is accurate, the SUBJUNCTIVE MOOD is vanishing from English and it's now common to hear statements such as: *If he WAS to return...* or *If I was to visit....*. These are now considered perfectly acceptable even though they do not use the SUBJUNCTIVE construction.

Comment: @RonaldSole - [I think it's a little strong to say "vanishing".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+he+were&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20he%20were%3B%2Cc0)  It's true that "was" is probably more common than once, but *were* is hardly moribund.

Comment: @stangdon If I be mistaken, I seek thy pardon!